# Stretching an image relative to screen size

Tags: android, layout, drawable

I have a layout that features six buttons. All of them have the size of 72x72dip, so they appear to be larger on small screens and vice versa.

How can I tackle this problem? I want the buttons to be relatively the same size (eg 10% of the screen's width), but I don't know how to do it.

This is how my layout looks:

[image]

The layout's sourcecode can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/Hj7Jx8Th).

Comment: please post only the code in question; nobody will dig through it to find the culprit ;)

Comment: I already did. The posted code is just for the buttons. Also the question is not about this particular code, but a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Did you fix all you 'image views' to layout_width & height of 72dip ?
2 - Normally 72dip is the same thing on every screen size... But you still can have 3(or 4 if you support XHDPI) resolution of your images...

2 - Add 4 différent fonder for you Drawable :

2.1 drawable

2.2 drawable-ldpi

2.3 drawable-mdpi

2.4 drawable-hdpi

Consider the following ratio for your images :
ldpi is 3
mdpi is 4
hdpi is 6

So make sure to make HDPI images first, so you can isealy resize other images applying ration 1.5 and 2 (just divide by 2 for LDPI for example).

3.By the way, why did you just did it all by yourself ? Seems you are on android 4.0, why don't you just use the new "DashBoard" class from Android ?

Comment: Yes, I already have different image sizes for different screen sizes, but all of them are 72x72dip.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this by setting the width and height to `wrap_content` and then tweaking the `layout_weight` on the ImageButton widgets so that each button takes up the same amount of space. I usually do `scaleType="center_inside"` to make them line up nicely. Then pad around the edges of the TableView with margins as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Few quick observations:

a. You do not need TableLayout, just use LinearLayout

b. You do not need separate ImageView and TextView, you can use Button and image to it using

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/"
```

c. Never use absolute values in width/height of any views, so use wrap_content.

Sample Layout should be like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

 <!-- Row 1 -->
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

 <Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:text="Preferences"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/Preferences" />

 <Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:text="Preferences"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/Preferences" />

 </LinearLayout>

  .
  .
  .   
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your improvements! **(a)** I tried that, but I could not get it to work. **(b)** I prefer using this approach, because it is not a button but a clickable layout (so it has a nice color change on click) **(c)** Before posting the question I actually did use `wrap_content`, but apparently I forgot to change it back before posting the code.

Comment: However Lint complains now: "Nested weights are bad for performance"

Comment: Also it doesn't work how I wanted it. On smaller screens, the images are way to big.

Comment: For complex layout, you will need to use nested weights there is no way around it. Can you paste the screenshot so that I can tell you the adjustments. Lint is just a warning tool and should be taken as that.